# bokeh: change line width on hover in multi line graph

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a graph with multiple lines. I want to make a line in bold when hovered. Other lines should be untouched.

In the example below, the tooltip works fine, but the hover_glyph doesn't. If I hover one line then both lines are getting wider. If I hover the second line, nothing happens to both lines. How to make it working?

```
x = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 100)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)

output_notebook()

source = ColumnDataSource(pd.DataFrame(data={'L1': y1, 'L2': y2}, index=x))
f = figure(tools='xwheel_zoom, wheel_zoom, pan', active_scroll='xwheel_zoom', active_drag='pan')

g1 = f.line(x='index', y='L1', source=source, color=Spectral11[1], legend_label='L1', name='L1') 
gg1 = g1.hover_glyph = Line(line_color=Spectral11[1], line_width=5)

g2 = f.line(x='index', y='L2', source=source, color=Spectral11[3], legend_label='L2', name='L2') 
gg2 = g2.hover_glyph = Line(line_color=Spectral11[3], line_width=4)

hover = HoverTool(renderers=[g2])
hover.tooltips=[
            ('both fields', '@L1'+':'+'@L2'),
            ('name', '$y'),
            ('Number', '$name')
        ]
f.add_tools(hover)

hover2 = HoverTool(renderers=[g1])
hover2.tooltips=[
            ('name', '$y'),
            ('Number', '$name')
        ]
f.add_tools(hover2)

show(f)
```

Comment: You could maybe make it a little easier for somebody to help if you edited the post to include the necessary imports.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me and I opend [issues #128459](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/12845) because of this.

Comment: Thank you for the ticket in bokeh github. There is good answer for this from mattpap: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/12845#issuecomment-1443921178

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two renderer are connected because they share the same `source`.

If you want to split the hover action, you have to split the `source` into two `sources`.

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral11
output_notebook()

x = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 100)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)

source1 = ColumnDataSource({'L1': y1, "index":x})
source2 = ColumnDataSource({'L1': y1,'L2': y2, "index":x})

p = figure(tools='xwheel_zoom, wheel_zoom, pan', active_scroll='xwheel_zoom', active_drag='pan')

g1 = p.line(x='index', y='L1', source=source1, color=Spectral11[1], legend_label='L1', name='L1',
            hover_line_color=Spectral11[1], hover_line_width=5)

# workaround for the hover information "both fields"
p.line(x='index', y='L1', source=source2, color=Spectral11[1], legend_label='L1', name='L2', line_width=0)

g2 = p.line(x='index', y='L2', source=source2, color=Spectral11[3], legend_label='L2', name='L2',
            hover_line_color=Spectral11[3], hover_line_width=4)

hover = HoverTool(renderers=[g2])
hover.tooltips=[
            ('both fields', '@L1:@L2'),
            ('name', '$y'),
            ('Number', '$name')
        ]
p.add_tools(hover)

hover2 = HoverTool(renderers=[g1])
hover2.tooltips=[
            ('name', '$y'),
            ('Number', '$name')
        ]
p.add_tools(hover2)

show(p)
```

Comment: You one hover tool information was a bit tricky. The workaround might be ok, but is far from perfect.

Comment: Nice.  I guess this is a case of "linked hover" behavior.  I'm guessing the whole row of the source is hovered together, but I have not found that in the docs.  I've only found one sorta relevant reference to shared "selections and hovered inspections" buried under a section on linked selection with filtered data, and that is about linking between different plots.

Comment: Exactly, the same answer gave mattpap on github: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/12845#issuecomment-1443921178 . It solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

A possible work-around might be to use `multi_line`.

For completeness, here is a slightly simpler, self-contained, working demo of the issue.  This snippet should highlight L1 but not L2 when L1 is hovered.  Instead, both lines are highlighted when L1 is hovered.

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral11
from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource

import numpy as np

output_notebook()

x = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 100)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)
source = ColumnDataSource({'L1': y1, 'L2': y2, 'index': x})

f = figure(tools='')
g1 = f.line(x='index', y='L1', source=source, color=Spectral11[1], legend_label='L1', name='L1',
            hover_line_width=4)
g2 = f.line(x='index', y='L2', source=source, color=Spectral11[3], legend_label='L2', name='L2',
           hover_line_width=4)

hover = HoverTool(renderers=[g1])  # Activate hover only for L1.
f.add_tools(hover)

show(f)
```

EDIT: ADDED POSSIBLE WORK-AROUND

If you are happy to work with multi-lines, the line highlighting feature seems to work for them so that might be a work-around.  I haven't tried to reproduce the tooltips shown in the original question, though.

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral11
from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource

import numpy as np

output_notebook()

x = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 100)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)

source = ColumnDataSource({
    "index": [x, x],
    "y": [y1, y2],
    "color": [Spectral11[1], Spectral11[3]],
    "label": ["L1", "L2"]
})

f = figure(tools='')
g = f.multi_line(xs="index", ys="y", source=source, color="color", legend_group="label",
                 hover_line_width=4)

hover = HoverTool(renderers=[g],
                  tooltips="@label: $data_x, $data_y")
f.add_tools(hover)

show(f)
```

Comment: This is not an answer. If you want to improve the question, you can request or apply some changes by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75512155/edit) the question.

Comment: I guess there is some risk that actual answers might never emerge if people overlook this question because it seems to already have an answer--that would be a shame.

Comment: @TMBaily: Your multipline workaround is very good. I want to mention that I had to set `hover = HoverTool(renderers=[g],tooltips=None)` to make it work in bokeh 3.0.3. Before there was an error in the browser console.

Comment: @mosc9575: Thanks.  I don't see that error, but I've got bokeh 2.3.2.